# Why does catching AggregateException cause CA2000 dispose warning?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, idisposable, aggregateexception

The code below causes a code analysis warning CA2000, claiming that I need to dispose of `getRequest` along all code paths before it goes out of scope. 
Tweaking the code slightly, for example removing the `when` from the `catch`, eliminates the warning.

```
try
{
    using (var getRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri))
    {
        using (var result = client.SendAsync(getRequest).Result)
        {
        }
    }
}
catch (AggregateException exc) when (exc.InnerExceptions.Count >= 0)
{
}
```

On which code path is dispose not called, and why does catch/when affect things?

Note: I'm using VS2015's built in code analysis. CA2000 is in the managed binary analysis ruleset, and is (for me) unchecked by default for new solutions. (VS2017 also emits the same warnings)

Comment: I took this hunk of code and popped it in an empty console app (added various local variables to make it compile) and click Analyse code in VS 2017 and it came up with nothing. What code analyser are you using?

Comment: I have enabled it, pasted your code and also don't get any error. Which framework are we talking about? Legacy or .NET Core?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue. It occurs in the debug build but not the release build. Still digging into the IL a bit to try to find out why...

Comment: @Rob yeah got it reproduced now

Comment: For people coming along who don't want to have to type everything into VS here is a link to the ILSpy decompiled C# code https://www.pastiebin.com/5babac6311371  and the ILSpy decompiled IL code: https://www.pastiebin.com/5babaceb7fd50

Comment: Slightly simpler code with the same problem: https://www.pastiebin.com/5babafcb1ddce